# Registering a JAR while running

Tags: java, jar, netbeans-platform

I want to have a modular application which registers JAR modules while running. For that purpose I'm using the Netbeans Lookup API.

The problem is that, I cannot copy some JAR file directly in the libraries folder because the running instance doesn't recognize it.
In the modules I have configured the `META-INF.services` with the package name of the interface and a module package name in it.

Here is a example of my code:

```
while(true){  
    Lookup lkp;
    Collection<TestInterface> tests = null;
    Template tmpl;
    final Lookup.Result rslt;

    lkp= Lookup.getDefault();
    //lkp=Lookups.forPath("modules-path");
    tmpl= new Template(TestInterface.class);
    rslt= lkp.lookup(testTemplate);
    tests = rslt.allItems();

    Lookup.getDefault().lookup(TestInterface.class);
        rslt.addLookupListener(new LookupListener() {
            @Override
            public void resultChanged(LookupEvent le) {
                reaction(rslt);
            }
        });

        reaction(rslt);
    }
}

private static void reaction(Lookup.Result r) {
    for (Iterator i = r.allInstances().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        TestInterface s = (TestInterface) i.next();
        System.out.println(s.somemethod());
    }
}
```

Any suggestions/hints how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use OSGi for your purpose, instead of Netbeans Lookup. Obviously, you have control on the jar files you need to load, so it should work fine.

You need to change your jar configuration in order to get a OSGi bundle. To do so, you have to change your MANIFEST.MF file, as explained here:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/OSGi/article.html#osgiarch_manifest
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2008/jw-03-osgi1.html?page=2

Then, you can activate the jar file using the BundleActivator you defined in your manifest, like explained here:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/OSGi/article.html#codebundle

Then, you can publish your bundle as a service and consume it in your application:

http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t90796.html

Comment: I know for OSGi and i will consider if lookup-api will be a bottleneck. Do you know if it's possible to "plug" modules without declaring the library, in OSGi. For example, i just put the jar in the folder while the main module is running, then the main module recognizes it and uses the methods from the module plugged on the fly?

Comment: I'm not myself an OSGi expert and I don't want to mislead you, but I don't think that's possible. So far as I know, a jar file needs to contain OSGi parameters in its MANIFEST.MF file in order to be recognized by OSGi. But a more experienced advice would be useful...